# Encrypt Radius password in python3

Tags: python-3.x, radius

I have used the following code in python2 to encrypt the Radius Password attribue:

```
    def Encrypt_Pass(password, authenticator, secret):
        m = md5()
        m.update(secret + authenticator)
        return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))
```

That does not work in python3, error for m.update line:

```
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

After i do add encoding:

```
   def Encrypt_Pass(password, authenticator, secret):
        m = md5()
        m.update(secret.encode('ascii') + authenticator.encode('ascii'))
        return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ ord(y)) for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))
```

I do still fail with:

```
TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
```

Now i am lost and forget the details of the algorithm, are you able to help ? How to change that last line to work with python3 ? (working perfectly fine for python2).

Update: I've did troubleshooting, with the code like this:

```
m = md5()
        m.update(secret.encode('ascii') + authenticator.encode('ascii'))
        print("Secret {}, encode {}".format(secret,secret.encode('ascii')))
        print("auth {}, encode {}".format(authenticator, authenticator.encode('ascii')))
        print("m digest: {}".format(m.digest()[:16]))
        print("passwd: {}".format(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16]))
        #return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ y) for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))
        for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]):
            print("JOIN ord x: {} y: {}".format(ord(x),y))
            a = "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ y))
            print("a: {}".format(chr(ord(x) ^ y)))
```

i got:

```
Secret cisco, encode b'cisco'
auth 5002CVWVKCX13QTN, encode b'5002CVWVKCX13QTN'
m digest: b'\xf8\xb9\xc2\x1foZ~h\xff@,\x87\x07\xcc:m'
passwd: cisco
JOIN ord x: 99 y: 248
a: 
JOIN ord x: 105 y: 185
a: Ð
JOIN ord x: 115 y: 194
a: ±
JOIN ord x: 99 y: 31
a: |
JOIN ord x: 111 y: 111
a: 
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 90
a: Z
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 126
a: ~
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 104
a: h
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 255
a: ÿ
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 64
a: @
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 44
a: ,
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 135
a: 
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 7
a: 
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 204
a: Ì
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 58
a: :
JOIN ord x: 0 y: 109
a: m
```

So it looks like instead of ord(y) i just have to use y ? But even with that password is still encoded incorrectly with python3 :(

Comment: try to convert the list compreshion to a for loop so you can debug the value of x and y

Comment: after troubleshooting: It looks like digest is working differently in python3 - is that possible ? That is because i can run without ord(y) - just y like this: "return "".join(chr(ord(x) ^ y) for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))" - i am not getting error, but the User-Password value is not encoded correctly still :( Do you see any other differences between how python2 and python3 executes this ?

Comment: OK, i have almost solved it. It's about chr() function - very different in python3 then python2. Still troubleshooting the details and how i can replace chr() with similar function in python3.....

Comment: OK, i have fixed, i had to replace my return line of code with the: "return b"".join(bytes([ord(x) ^ y]) for x, y in zip(password.ljust(16, '\0')[:16], m.digest()[:16]))" - so 3 significant changes - bloody/crapy Python......